# How to reset kmail?

Tags: kmail, akonadi

There must be some corruption to my message store (pop3) as kmail keeps crashing and hanging. I followed the following info to try and reset kmail: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/pim/kmail/clean-start-after-a-failed-migration.html but after point (3) all it did was clean up akonadi, all the messages are still in kmail, and it still crashes and/or hangs.

How do I also remove the messages for a fresh 'factory' start ? Is it enough to remove the folder holding them (~/.local/share/local-mail/) ?

Answer (score 3):

The instructions at https://userbase.kde.org/KMail/FAQs_Hints_and_Tips#Clean_start_after_a_failed_migration worked for me.
Do NOT remove ~/.local/share/local-mail, that's where "Local Folders" stores emails, i.e. what you delete from there will be lost forever.

When using IMAP, this folder isn't used.
When using POP, the emails are downloaded into that folder, so unless you enabled keeping a copy on the server, deleting that directory will delete your emails for good.

Answer (score 0):

**Try deleting the `.kmail` folder.**

Go to `/home` and simultaneously press **Ctrl** + **H**.
This will show your system's hidden files.(If I installed Abobe AIR, it would show `.adobe`) Navigate to the `.kmail` file and delete it. This will delete all your mail and reset your settings for kmail. 
Open kmail and it should appear as it does on first opening it. This is essentially a factory reset for kmail.

Comment: @dargaud did this work?

Comment: no .kmail, and .kmail2 was empty. I exported all my messages and settings, deleted ~/.local/share/local-mail/, fsck/vacuum/stop/start akonadi as in the link above, then reimported, sorted the mess of the target directories in the filters and so far so good.

Comment: try uninstalling it and then reinstalling it.

Comment: Well, the above didn't work. I just did uninstall/purge. It removed a whole bunch of dependencies, and when I reinstalled kmail, it didn't reinstall any of them. Upon launch mysql/akonadi has been running hard for a few hours. We'll see.

Comment: That failed also. I managed to export my messages to Thunderbird, so I'm giving up.

Comment: @dargaud Bummer. Thunderbird works well. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, so far so good, no regrets. The migration was tricky, I wrote (poorly) something about it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/873917/migrating-from-kmail-to-thunderbird